# Keyboard lag & mouse selection issues

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, troubleshooting, input-device

A few weeks ago I started experiencing typing lag which is 'somewhat' intermittent.  It happens in all programs including browsers & Microsoft Word (though not as often).  I also have experienced problems with the mouse selecting text.  When trying to select text is lags, sometimes selects more or less than I want, and wont unselect when I click somewhere else for at least two seconds.  I don't remember installing or updating anything specifically before the problems started to appear.

---

Windows 7 Professional SP1 on Dell studio XPS

---

I've tried:

1. Turning off all extra services
2. Using a USB (wired) keyboard
3. Using two different types of wireless mice.
4. Disabling the touch pad.
5. Full virus scan (Norton)
6. Disabled virus scanner
7. Ran memory check using [MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) - no errors
8. Windows is up to date (at least as of a few minutes ago :-)
9. Drivers are up to date

---

Short of wiping the hard drive clean and reloading, is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Before you get to the wiping and reloading point. If you have System restore turned on (and most do by default unless you turned it off) you can restore your system to an earlier point in time before all the delays started.

Even before that though I would check your running processes as one of them may be the culprit. Turn off all unecessary processes and start there. Or you can do what's called a "Clean Boot" Turning off all processes at the start and then enabling them 1/2 at a time to see if the problem persists.

More detailed information on how to use a clean boot to troubleshoot can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).